# Object ***********/******.jpg doesn't exist, Firebase Storage

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, firebase-storage

My problem is when I run the application, this error appears in the console

Optional ("Users Profile / Kk1kKMF89BH778vgd788ju7.jpg does not exist.")

But the file exists in my Firebase storage. I try to download the image to a UIImage named `phSelfie`.

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SeeSelfieViewController: UIViewController {

var storage = FIRStorage.storage()

@IBOutlet var phSelfie: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gsRef = storage.reference(forURL: "gs://******-****.appspot.com/profileUsers/")

    let user = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!

    let imageRef = gsRef.child("\(user.uid).jpg")

    imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in

        if error != nil {

            print("\(error?.localizedDescription)") <------ This run the error!!

        } else {

            let imageSelfie = UIImage(data: data!)

            self.phSelfie.image = imageSelfie

            print("Succes")

        }

    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few issues:

- `storage.reference(forURL: "gs://******-****.appspot.com/profileUsers/")` should be an HTTP URL, or you should just use `storage.reference().child("profileUsers")`
- `Users Profile / Kk1kKMF89BH778vgd788ju7.jpg` seems to have spaces in the object, which would be percent escaped `%20` in the actual object name.
- `Users Profile` seems to not match `profileUsers`, which is what the object name above says...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Press Upload Button Action
    @IBAction func uploadButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print("Upload Button pressed")
        
        // Create a root reference
        
        let storage = Storage.storage()
        let storageReferance = storage.reference()
        
        let mediaFolder = storageReferance.child("media")
        print("Media Folder Created")
        
        
        if let data = UIImageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
            print("Image Selected")
            
            let imageReference = mediaFolder.child("image.jpg")
            imageReference.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata,error) in
                
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    print("Image selection error")
                    
                }else{
                    imageReference.downloadURL { url, error in
                        if error == nil{
                                        let imageURL = url?.absoluteString
                                        print("Image selection SUCCESS")
                                        print(imageURL)
                        }

                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have same problem above code says; Optional("Object media/image.jpg does not exist.")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33747675)